# Textarea caret is not rotated on iOS 11.2.5

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari

I have a textarea that is rotated 45deg

```
textarea {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

<textarea></textarea>
```

The problem is that on an iOS device the text caret doesn't rotate, it shows as a big weird box.

```css
textarea {
  border: 1em dashed red;
  padding: 1em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Cursor in iOS: bugged
</h2>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>close keyboard</button>
```

Example on CodePen https://codepen.io/brunolm/pen/eVBdaj

Is there any fix for that? Or another way to rotate the element?

Comment: you are going to have to create or add your own cursor

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create or add your own custom cursor, or just find one on google.

This [site](http://www.rw-designer.com) is good to find some custom cursors

```css
textarea {
  border: 1em dashed red;
  padding: 1em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=77519), auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Cursor in iOS: bugged
</h2>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>close keyboard</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've said `caret` instead. It's not the mouse cursor, it is that thing that blinks in the textarea when you are typing something.

Comment: @BrunoLM i see. I cant help further ass i dont own an ios. Good luck